# How to pass rating selected by customer to component in angular

Tags: angular

I am using angular 6 and material library. I can display rating in  but i am not able to pass updated rating to component. Here is my code,

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ItemQuality">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Item Quality</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><star-rating-comp [starType]="'icon'" [(rating)] ="element.ItemQuality"></star-rating-comp></td>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: can you confirm if your rating is changed in your ``star-rating-comp`` ?

Comment: yes that was changed

Comment: why don't you bind a function to  ``(ratingChanged)`` and change the value of ``ItemQuality`` ?

Comment: tried this <star-rating-comp [starType]="'icon'" [(rating)] ="element.ItemQuality" (ratingChange)="element.ItemQuality" ></star-rating-comp> but no result

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ngx-bootstrap` library for `rating`

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/how-to-pass-rating-selected-by-customer-to-component-in-angular?file=app/table-basic-example.html)**

for configure  `ngx-bootstrap` - [Document URL](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/rating#rating-dynamic)

install library - `npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`

> app.module.ts

```
import { RatingModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/rating';

@NgModule({
  imports: [RatingModule.forRoot()]
})
export class AppModule(){}
```

> Component.html

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <rating [(ngModel)]="element.rating" [max]="5" [readonly]="false"></rating>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: i am using material in my project, so how can i use bootstrap for rating only

Comment: npm install ngx-bootstrap --save

Answer (score 0):

A custom two way data binding is implemented here using `rating`

So you can do something like this :

```
  <ng-container matColumnDef="ItemQuality">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Item Quality</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"><star-rating-comp [starType]="'icon'" [(rating)] ="element.ItemQuality" (ratingChange)="someFunction($event)"></star-rating-comp></td>
  </ng-container>
```

basically you've `[(rating)]` which consists of `[rating]` and `(ratingChange)` . Listen to `(ratingChange)` event .

in your `component`  implement the `someFunction($event)` .

in your `.ts` :

```
someFunction(event){
 //event will have your rating which is changed
}
```

Comment: ratingChange never call function someFunction(event) in my component

Comment: @Alina ``star-rating-comp`` can you link me the module ?